# balanced binary search tree using sortedset

Tags: c#, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Please help I've been trying to generate a random binary search tree of size 1024 and the elements needs to be random sortedset ... I'm able to write a code to create a binary search tree manually by adding elements manually but I'm unablele yo write a code that would generate a random balanced binary tree of size 1024 then use try to find a key in that tree ... please please and thank u ahead ....

**Edit** added code from comments

ya it is homework... and this is what i got so far as code:

```
using System; 
namespace bst { 
    public class Node { 
        public int value; 
        public Node Right = null; 
        public Node Left = null; 

        public Node(int value) 
        { 
            this.value = value; 
        } 
    } 

    public class BST { 
        public Node Root = null; 
        public BST() { }

        public void Add(int new_value) 
        { 
            if(Search(new_value)) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("value (" + new_value + ") already");
            }
            else
            {
                AddNode(this.Root,new_value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use recursion.
Each branch generates a new branch, select the middle item in the unsorted set, the median. Put it in the current item in the tree. Copy all items less than the median to another array, send that new array to the call of the same method. Copy all items greater than the median to another array, send that new array to the call of the same method.\

Balanced trees have to have an odd number of items, unless the main parent node is not filled in. You need to decide if there are two values that are the Median, whether the duplicate belongs on the lower branch or upper branch. I put duplicates on the upper branch in my example.

The median will be the number where an equal amount of numbers is less than and greater than the number. 1,2,3,3,4,18,29,105,123
In this case, the median is 4, even though the mean (or average) is much higher.

I didn't include code that determines the median.

```
BuildTreeItem(TreeItem Item, Array Set)  
{
  Array Smalls;
  Array Larges;
  Median = DetermineMedian(Set);
  Item.Value = Median;
  if(Set.Count() == 1)
    return;  
  for (int i = 0; int i < Set.Count(); i++)
  {
    if(Set[i] < Median)
    {
      Smalls.new(Set[i]);
    }
    else
    {
      Larges.new(Set[i]);
    }
  }
  Item.Lower = new TreeItem;
  Item.Upper = new TreeItem;
  BuildTreeItem(TreeItem.Lower, Smalls);
  BuildTreeItem(TreeItem.Upper, Larges);
}
```

Comment: so all what i would need is just to add the code for the Median and that would generate the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is homework the easiest solution would be to sort data first and then build a tree by using middle item as root and descending down each half. Method proposed by Xaade is similar <strike>, but much slower due to DetermineMedian complexity</strike>.

The other option is to actually look at algorithms that build balanced trees (like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree ) to see if it fits your requirements.

EDIT: removing incorrect statement about speed of Xaade algorithm - it is actually as fast as quick sort (n log n - check each element on every level of recursion with log n levels of recursion), not sure why I estimated it slower.

Comment: using System;

namespace bst
{
    public class Node
    {
        public int value;
        public Node Right = null;
        public Node Left = null;

        public Node(int value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }



    public class BST
    {
        public Node Root = null;

        public BST()
        {
        }

Comment: public void Add(int new_value)
        {
            if(Search(new_value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("value (" + new_value + ") already");
            }
            else
            {
                AddNode(this.Root,new_value);
            }

        }

Comment: basically i'm completely lost it is a homework problem but first i need to deteremine how to make this tree to work on my homework and starting avering out the time and work on search functions but i'm just stcuk it would be awesome if i get help for the coding part...

Comment: Depends on the method of sorting. A bubble sort would be slower than my algorithm. Quicksorting would be faster though

Comment: So far, I cannot find a method for selecting medians recursively that would be faster than simply sorting the set to begin with.

Comment: I wonder, since we know it's going to be a binary tree. Wouldn't it be simpler to build the tree and add pointers to the nodes into an array, then sort the original array into the pointer array.